# Date not showing in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have View with div where I need to show date

I write this JavaScript code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dateObj = new Date();
  var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
  var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
  var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

  newdate = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
  $("#id").append(newdate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="date" style="width: 100%; height: 10%; background:#1d69b4 ">

</div>
```

Comment: `$("#date)` use this. and closing as typo error

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$("#id").append(newdate);
```

To

```
$("#date").append(newdate);
```

This is a selector for getting an element with ID as date

Answer (score 1):

You where just pointing to the wrong id. It should have been `#date`:

```
$("#date").append(newdate);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dateObj = new Date();
  var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
  var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
  var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

  newdate = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
  $("#date").append(newdate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="date" style="width: 100%; height: 10%;background:#1d69b4 ">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong selector 
Change

```
$("#id").append(newdate);
```

to

```
 $("#date").append(newdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you have div `id='date'` and to display your formatted date string into that div then you should be using `.text() or .html()` instead of `.append()`

So your script should be

```
$("#date").text(newdate);

// or

$("#date").html(newdate);
```